# vector.push_back() being very slow

Tags: c++, vector, time-complexity

I was on a project that had a time complexity of O(N^3) where N is around 300. I was using vectors of tuples, and the time it took to run was very slow, taking well above 5 seconds.

I investigated further and ran a basic time test of my original program.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<tuple<int, int, int>> pos[305];

int main() {
    auto start = clock();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 300; i ++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 300*300; j ++) {
            pos[i].push_back({0, 0, 0});
        }
    }
    cout << (double)(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

This code above was the code that I had used. On average, it ran took 3.5 seconds to run. From previous knowledge, vector.push_back() was an amortized o(1), so it will approximately run 300^3 = 27000000. Even with the constant factor of 3 for the vector of tuples, this program should run well within a second.

Why is this code taking so long to execute, is it to do with the speed of vector.push_back()?

Comment: How do you compile the code? If you enable optimizations, it will take 0 seconds.

Comment: You're doing 27 million memory reallocations here.  Just do `pos[i].reserve(300*300)` before you start the inner loop and it'll zip right along.  `vector.push_back` is not amortized O(1).  It's O(logN) because it has to reallocate and copy the memory.

Comment: @273K I compile without any optimizations, just C++ 11 if that's what you mean. What optimisations should I include to decrease runtime?

Comment: @TimRoberts I included `pos[i].reserve(300*300)` and it improved slightly to an average of 2.7 seconds runtime.

Comment: Well, you're also constructing 27 million tuple objects.

Comment: To test it out, I changed the vector to vector of integers. The runtime became 0.9 seconds, but I think that's still higher than it should be. (I used the reserve(300*300) as well)

Comment: *What optimisations should I include to increase runtime?* I thought you wanted to decrease it.

Comment: Sorry typo, I've changed it.

Comment: Any benchmarks w/o compiler optimizations make little sense.

Comment: This isn't really meant to be a formal benchmark, I'm just testing locally to see how it compares on my device.

Comment: This code (even *without* the suggested changes) runs in less than a second on my PC when compiled more reasonably (just `-O2`, nothing fancy like target specifiers)

Comment: @TimRoberts - No, there shouldn't be 27 million reallocations (unless compiler's library is sloppily written which _may_ be a possibility). `std::vector` usually allocates new space proportionally to the current size, not one element at a time. I think knowing the compiler might shed some light on the subject.

Comment: Yes, I exaggerated for effect.  Most libraries use an exponential algorithm.  It's still a of heap mucking.

Comment: Always test in release builds with optimizations enabled (and make sure nothing else is running on your system). Side notes : using `std::tuple` outside of template code is just plain lazy and doesn't help to make code more readable.  Declare your own struct with three readable member variables that add semantics. Also never use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` (not standard C++) and `using namespace std;` (will bite you later in big projects). 
`

Comment: `push_back`  will does copy/move source to underling pointer. `emplace_pack` will construct at underling pointer. [reference example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) . if you can't  avoid `push_back` , create vector to store pointer instead. Copy/move pointer is cheaper than whole content.

Comment: @JakkapongRattananen not always, if the type being pused back can be moved from and you pass an rvalue reference to that type (std::move) it will move too

Comment: @TimRoberts *"vector.push_back is not amortized O(1)"* - Wrong, it is.

Comment: if you don't really need contiguous container. I suggest [deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque). c++ deque is store content in chunk. It don't need to move whole content when not enough contiguous 
 space.

Comment: A deque might be faster for inserting the elements, but it will then be about half speed for accessing them later. A tradeoff to consider.

Comment: @JakkapongRattananen on the contrary, I recommend using vector by default every time. vector almost always wins, even in cases where you think it shouldn't. Not always, but almost. deque is something that sounds good in theory, but in practice almost always lets you down.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for a C array of vectors?